# Why does centipede keep running into my hair and bite me?

Tags: zoology, entomology

After I moved into a new house in the suburban area, I was bitten by an unknown creature near my spine at mid-night. I felt painful and dizzy. However, after 15 mins, I no longer felt dizzy and the pain faded, so I did not see a doctor.

Serveral months later, the same thing happened again at mid-night, the creature ran into my hair (I have long hair) and bit the back of my neck. This time we figured out that it was probably a centipede, as it was red, had many legs, and ran fast.

Yesterday, a centipede ran into my hair again in the morning. Luckily, I felt something was in my hair and I manged to shake off the centipede, so it did not bite me.

Why does centipede keep running into my hair and bite me and what should I do?

Comment: It could be useful to first identify the centipede. Did you catch it? The more common centipede in houses is [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutigera_coleoptrata], I have seen it in my house but it never tried to bite us.

Comment: @heracho Yes, we caught it but sadly we didn't take any photo of it. It looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geophilus_flavus (brownish red & long)